# Cannot run C program from Java using Cygwin

Tags: java, c, windows, gcc, cygwin

I'm trying to make my first Java/C program using JNI. Here's how 'my' code looks - it's copied from [this](http://stuf.ro/calling-c-code-from-java-using-jni) website:

```
/* HelloWorld.java */

public class HelloWorld {
    native void helloFromC();
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("ctest");
    }
    static public void main(String argv[]) {
        HelloWorld helloWorld = new HelloWorld();
        helloWorld.helloFromC();
    }
}
```

C part:

```
/* ctest.c */

#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloWorld_helloFromC
  (JNIEnv * env, jobject jobj)
{
    printf("Hello from C!\n");
}
```

Through Cygwin, I succesfully did

```
javac HelloWorld.java
javah HelloWorld
```

to create a header file like this:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class HelloWorld */

#ifndef _Included_HelloWorld
#define _Included_HelloWorld
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     HelloWorld
 * Method:    helloFromC
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloWorld_helloFromC
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

So far so good. I can also compile the C program using:

```
$ gcc -D __int64="long long" -shared -I"D:\Programy\Java\JDK 8u31\include" 
-I"D:\Programy\Java\JDK 8u31\include\win32" ctest.c -o ctest.dll
```

Now I should be able to do

```
java HelloWorld
```

to see output from C, but instead I'm getting this error:

```
$ java HelloWorld
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000018011ae47, pid=3156, tid=1176
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_31-b13) (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.31-b07 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [cygwin1.dll+0xdae47]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# D:\Dokumenty\Fifth\src\hs_err_pid3156.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

**What I have tried:**

1. Using `-mno-cygwin` flag when compiling, but since I have the newest version of Cygwin installed, it's not supported anymore.
2. Using `-mno-cygwin` flag with `gcc-3` instead of gcc - but Cygwin doesn't recognize *gcc-3* command.
3. Adding an environment variable. This seems to be the common solution, but somehow it doesn't work for me. On my system, Cygwin is installed in `D:\Programy\Cygwin`, therefore the folder I added to `PATH` is `D:\Programy\Cygwin\bin`, as shown in the [picture](http://s4.postimg.org/pqqlhnuzh/image.png) (sorry for external link, I don't have enough reputation to post pictures).

From all the answers I've read, this one *should* work, but it doesn't. Is there a problem with Cygwin not being directly in C:\Cygwin? Or am I doing something else wrong? I checked the folder and there *is* cygwin1.dll, it's not missing.

I'm running on Windows 8, 64-bit. Version of Cygwin: 1.7.35-1, installed the whole Devel package. GCC version is 4.9.2.

*Sorry for the long post, I just wanted to provide as much information as I could. I've been stuck with this problem for several days now and will be glad for any advice.*

**Edit:** I just noticed that compiling my C file with `gcc` command as above doesn't produce any executable file, which I find very strange. It also doesn't throw any error or warning. Any ideas on this one? Could that be the source of my trouble?

**Edit 2:** I just found out this should not be an issue, I'm actually making a library, not an executable file.

**Edit 3:** Okay, I'm giving up. It seems like much bigger issue than I initially thought it would be. The reason this cannot be done is that `cygwin1.dll` cannot be dynamically loaded, because it needs 4k of bottom stack bytes to be free when it's initializing - which might be a problem if it's being called from JNI. There *are* some ways to overcome it; if you're looking for a solution, [this post](http://lists-archives.com/cygwin/28776-creating-a-dll-in-cygwin-for-use-with-jni-without-mno-cygwin.html) sums up nicely what needs to be done and [this one](http://elliotth.blogspot.cz/2005/08/porting-jni-code-to-win32-with-cygwin.html) can also be useful. For my project, it's just not worth it - but good luck.

Comment: Don't worry about the lengthy posting - I think it is a great first question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that the reason this cannot be done is that `cygwin1.dll` cannot be dynamically loaded, because it needs 4k of bottom stack bytes to be free when it's initializing - which might be a problem if it's being called from JNI.

There *are* some ways to overcome it; if you're looking for a solution, **[this post](http://lists-archives.com/cygwin/28776-creating-a-dll-in-cygwin-for-use-with-jni-without-mno-cygwin.html)** sums up nicely what needs to be done and [this one](http://elliotth.blogspot.cz/2005/08/porting-jni-code-to-win32-with-cygwin.html) can also be useful. I also found an explicit solution [here](https://www.sourceware.org/ml/cygwin/2004-06/msg00274.html).

Answer (score 2):

add header file which was generated using `javah` in your c file

```
/* ctest.c */
#include "HelloWorld.h"
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloWorld_helloFromC
(JNIEnv * env, jobject jobj)
{
printf("Hello from C!\n");
}
```

and run using

```
java -Djava.library.path=. HelloWorld
```

if it does not work than try

```
java HelloWorld
```

a much more detailed example is explained in [this site](http://javapapers.com/core-java/how-to-call-a-c-program-from-java/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added the header file as you correctly suggested and compiled the file again, but the problem (error with cygwin1.dll) still persists, no matter if I specify the java.library.path or not.

Comment: @Tilwaen okk than can you just follow the given site to get your desired result? if its possible?

Comment: I followed the instructions, even made new project with the exact same code they provided (I only added two libraries to C file which they omitted), compiled with Cygwin just as I did in my original post and got the exact same error. I also downloaded TCC which they use, but somehow can't get it to work - Cygwin has its terminal, but this compiler doesn't seem to have one and classic Windows cmd doesn't recognize _tcc_ command, so I'm a bit confused about how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

As i can't comment with my low reputation i'll say it there.

1. What is the result of `echo %PATH%` in cmd, do you clearly see the path to Cygwin's binaries ?
2. What are the contents of the logs after `java HelloWorld` in `D:\Dokumenty\Fifth\src\hs_err_pid3156.log` ?

I'll edit this answer after yours.

Comment: 1. Yes, there is D:\Programy\Cygwin\bin;
- pressed enter too soon, editing -

Comment: Oh well, comments may only be edited for 5 minutes... Sorry I can't edit the previous one. As to your questions:

1. Yes, there is `D:\Programy\Cygwin\bin;` among other paths.
2. Because the log is quite long, I put it on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/jBYLrBMc). I already deleted the log to my original post, this one is related to the code on website that Bhargav Modi posted, which I tried later, but I think it relates to the same issue (cygwin1.dll).

Comment: To test if it works, open a cmd, go to your `D:\Programy` for example and try write `ls`. If it works, it shows that there is no problem with your path. If it doesn't recognize your `ls`, means it can't acces your `/usr/bin` as your program with `cygwin1.dll`

Comment: I succesfully went to `D:\Programy`. `ls` command worked flawlessly, it found every folder, including the Cygwin one.

Comment: I don't know sorry. Maybe try `java -Djava.library.path="D:\Programy\Cygwin\bin" HelloWorld`

Comment: Found something, try to add the path to binaries in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` instead of `PATH`. Look at the comments [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/377174/java/java/java-library-path).

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not working; this time I got the `Unsatisfied Link Exception` as there wasn't any `ctest.dll` in the target directory. I even tried copying my `ctest.dll` library to `D:\Programy\Cygwin\bin`, as well as `cygwin1.dll` to directory with source files after that, but neither worked (`Exception Access Violation` again). Thank you for your time and effort anyway!   Edit: I'll try that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` thing.

Comment: I can't find `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in my system environment variables; even in the link you posted, they say it's on UNIX systems, but I work on Windows. Should I attempt to create new system environment variable?

Comment: Try to add it : `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/you/want` in cygwin (it'll be temporary) or in the .bashrc so it'll initialize every launch

Comment: Still no progress, even with the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set as you suggested. I noticed the most strange thing now, however - and I'm a bit ashamed I didn't notice it earlier - when compiling the C file with gcc command, it actually doesn't make any executable file. It also doesn't throw any error or warning, just _nothing_. I'll update my original question with this information, maybe it will help somehow.

Answer (score -1):

I figured out a solution to this problem. When running the configure script, use

```
./configure --disable-static --enable-shared --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32
```

The last flag uses the mingw compiler that comes packaged with Cygwin. Mingw links against Microsoft's msvcrt.dll rather that the cygwin1.dll.