# Java code hangs when using native library with JNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I am trying to learn to use JNI to get access to a native library from inside Java code. I have used a hello world example to attempt to get an idea of how this works. Right now, when I run the Java code, either it silently crashes straight away or sometimes it gets to where I am calling a function from a native library before it hangs.

This is the Java code "TestJNI.java":

```
public class TestJNI {   
    static {      
        System.loadLibrary("greet");   
    }   
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Hello1");
        System.out.println("Hello2");
        new TestJNI().greetings();   
        System.out.println("Hello3");
    }
    private native void greetings();
}
```

This is the C code "greet.c":

```
#include "TestJNI.h"
#include <stdio.h>
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_TestJNI_greetings(JNIEnv *env,jobject jobj) {
   printf("Hello from Visual C++!\n");
}
```

This is how I try to run the code:

```
javac TestJNI.java
javac -h . TestJNI.java
gcc -shared -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\include" -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\include\win32" greet.c -o greet.dll -fPIC 
java TestJNI
```

Generating the header file with the above command results in the following header file TestJNI.h:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class TestJNI */

#ifndef _Included_TestJNI
#define _Included_TestJNI
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     TestJNI
 * Method:    greetings
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_TestJNI_greetings
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

There is a similar thread from years ago [JNI program hanging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438051/jni-program-hanging) but with no solution.

Comment: Please post an [mcve].  What exactly is in `TestJNI.h`?

Comment: @jwdonahue I didn't realise that it would be important since I gave the command I used to generate it but nonetheless I added it to the main post now.

Comment: Which GCC is this exactly? From the paths it looks like you're on Windows. If you're using MinGW, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689074/build-a-jni-dll-using-mingw

Comment: Yes, I am using Windows, however, I am using Cygwin. Also to clarify, I will add this to the post, the code never runs successfully. Either it hangs or it silently crashes straight away.

Comment: Maybe this will help? [The difference between System.load and System.loadLibrary in Java](https://www.pixelstech.net/article/1549365534-The-difference-between-System-load-and-System-loadLibrary-in-Java)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried using both System.load and System.loadLibrary and both exhibit the same issues. Either the program silently crashes straight away, it gets to the `new TestJNI().greetings();` line and crashes, or it hangs straight away, or it hangs when it gets to the `new TestJNI().greetings();` line. No errors whatsoever. If I try loading the wrong library (say, a file that doesn't exist) I get the expected UnsatisfiedLinkError.

Comment: Seems like building JNI libraries using cygwin can be problematic. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413290/using-java-jni-on-cygwin and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29487061/cannot-run-c-program-from-java-using-cygwin

Comment: If you are on Windows, and you want to play with `JNI` as if on `Linux`, then I strongly suggest to trying things out inside `Docker` - you will definitely keep your sanity level unaffected.

Comment: @Michael thank you, switching to MinGW solved my problem!